# writing string that defines a e i o u in a sentence with the number of variables of each

Tags: python, string, variables, input, numbers

I need help as a beginner in python:

Write a program that:
Defines a counter for each vowel (e.g a_counter = 0 )
Prompt the user for input with the prompt:  Please enter your sentence:
Capture  the input and store it in a variable
Loop through the user input and count all the vowels.
Once you have traversed the string and counted all the vowels, display the following messages:

The number of a's or A's in the user input  is ##

The number of e's or E's in the user input  is ##

The number of i's or I's in the user input  is ##

The number of o's or O's in the user input  is ##

The number of u's or U's in the user input  is ##

The number of y's or Y's in the user input  is ##

what if I want to include the sentence from the input where it outputs "user input" instead? –

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to count letters in a string, I suggest feeding the string to `collections.Counter`.  You can also save yourself a lot of copying and pasting by going over the vowels in a loop when it's time to print the output:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = input("Please enter your sentence:  ")
c = Counter(sentence.lower())
for v in "aeiou":
    print(f"The number of {v}'s or {v.upper()}'s in '{sentence}' is {c[v]}")
```

```
Please enter your sentence:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The number of a's or A's in 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' is 1
The number of e's or E's in 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' is 3
The number of i's or I's in 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' is 1
The number of o's or O's in 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' is 4
The number of u's or U's in 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' is 2
```

Comment: what if I want to include the sentence from the input where it outputs "user input" instead?

Comment: Assign the result of `input()` to a variable before you pass it to `Counter`, and then you can include it in your `print` statement as well.